# FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED locking table not being used in select statement Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, cursor, locking

I'm stuck in a situation where I am using a select statement with FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED.
Below query is part of a procedure which is being called from multiple parallel Jjobs running in RAC environment:

```
CURSOR MyCursor IS
SELECT A.ID, A.NEXTSEQNBR, A.EVENTTYPCD, A.EVMEVENTID , B.EVENTTTIMESTAMP 
FROM Table1 A 
INNER JOIN Table2 B ON A.ID = B.ID 
       AND A.NEXTSEQNBR - 1 = B.SEQNBR 
WHERE B.STATCD = 'MYVAL' 
AND MOD(A.ID, 1 ) = 0 
FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;
```

Table1 has a master table named EVENTTYPTABLE1. Table1.EVENTTYPCD column is a foreign key referencing EVENTTYPTABLE1.

In the production environment, I was checking the locked objects and found that master table EVENTTYPTABLE1 is being locked, even though I am not using master table EVENTTYPTABLE1 in the above query. I was expecting Table1 and Table2 table in a lock situation because of the FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED. But why EVENTTYPTABLE1? I am missing something?

Of course the cursor is being opened and fetched in the procedure.

Comment: I'm not in front of an Oracle instance right now to answer more completely.  However, as of Oracle 11.1.0.6, DML against a child table takes an `SX` mode DML lock on the parent table.  Refer to Oracle Support note 5909305.8.

Comment: Please share the link for the point you are referring to.

Comment: I cannot share the link -- the support note is only accessible via Oracle's support website.  Your Oracle license should entitle you to register there.

Comment: Can you explain what your "situation" actually is? Do the locks on the parent table lead to errors or job failures?

Comment: no errors, but it is causing the job to slow down and wait until the parent one releases the lock

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you do with the selected data. Your Cursor includes the foreign key column `A.EVENTTYPCD`. If your process updates that column you will see row exclusive (RX) AKA subexclusive table (SX) locks on the parent table:

```
LOCK_TYPE  LMODE          OBJECT_NAME
---------  -------------  --------------
TM         row-X (SX)     EVENTTYPTABLE1
TM         row-X (SX)     EVENTTYPTABLE1
TM         row-X (SX)     TABLE1
TM         row-X (SX)     TABLE1
TX         exclusive (X)
```

But if the process doesn't touch the foreign key you won't

```
LOCK_TYPE  LMODE          OBJECT_NAME
---------  -------------  --------------
TM         row-X (SX)     TABLE1
TX         exclusive (X)
```

---

Oracle introduced this behavior in 11.1.0.6.to fix a bug. It's documented in an Oracle Support Note, 5909305.8. It is a contravention of Oracle Support T&Cs to publish Support Notes (or any other MOS material) without permission of Oracle but you should try Googling for it ;)